# Android - default dark mode

Tags: java, android, android-dark-theme

I want to implement in my app Dark mode. In default I wish it been following by the system, so in Main Activity I've placed:

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
```

It works fine, but I if user wants to change its mind and select certain option in my app menu to toggle off/on dark mode, activity is restarting and app's still following system rules. How can I change that?

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_color_mode) {
        if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        else
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: please share when do you set `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`, is it in `onCreate()` .. please replay with @Zain to be notified

Comment: @Zain thank you for commitment. Code responsible for option you mentioned, is within `onCreate()`. Mechanism that allows user to change mode is not within `onCreate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Code responsible for option you mentioned, is within onCreate(). Mechanism that allows user to change mode is not within onCreate()

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    }
}
```

When you explicitly change the dark mode, Android recreates the activity and hence calls `onCreate` again.

So, after you change the dark mode you won't notice a change, as `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM` is called again when `onCreate` is called by the system.

To make this works you can save a value into `SharedPreference` that can be checked in `onCreate` before setting the system dark mode.

This can be a boolean that you can toggle when you want to manually change the dark mode.

Here is a sample

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isSystem = prefs.getBoolean("IS_SYSTEM", true);
        if (isSystem) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        }       
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_color_mode) {
            if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            else
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("IS_SYSTEM", false).apply();
            return true;
        }   
    
}
```

**UPDATE**

> that works perfect, but when I quit application and then launch again, default system mode is active although I've switched it. Is possible here to make it works in that way?

You can use another `SharedPreference` boolean to be saved permanently

```
public class MainActivityextends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isSystem = prefs.getBoolean("IS_SYSTEM", true);
        boolean isNight = prefs.getBoolean("IS_NIGHT", false);

        if (isSystem) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        } else if (isNight) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }   
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_color_mode) {

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("IS_NIGHT", false).apply();
    
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                        AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("IS_NIGHT", true).apply();
            }

            prefs.edit().putBoolean("IS_SYSTEM", false).apply();
            return true;
        }   
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect, but when I quit application and then launch again, default system mode is active although I've switched it.  Is possible  here to make it works in that way?

Comment: @amtrax thanks please check updated answer

Answer (score -2):

Try this option:

```html
boolean isNightModeOn;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO){
            isNightModeOn = false; // Set Text
        }
        else if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            isNightModeOn = true; // Set Text
        }
        else {AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        };
```

This is a default dark background setting. Then you can switch in your own way.

Comment: Usually only code answers are deleted. Please explain your solution.